# Using Google Maps API to track a specific device GPS

Tags: google-maps

I want to create a website that has a map that will track my phone's location. I'm not asking for specifics here. Just is it possible to do without creating my own app on my phone and using the Google Maps API or is there a lot more that I need?

Comment: A tiny bit more... For your purposes Google Maps will only visualize location data. You will need to get the GPS location data from the device somehow (e.g. `navigator.geolocation` in JavaScript will get location data from iOS devices depending on location services settings but its in no way "live")... does Find My iPhone have an API?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to access the phone's location from a source outside the phone, for example, loading the website on a computer and see the phone's location. From my searches geolocation gives the location of the device you are currently accessing from correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need two apps:

- A server application that listens to the phone and displays the phone's location
- An app on your phone that reports the geolocation to the server

Both should be fairly trivial, but it does mean you'll have to have the server application hosted somewhere. You can't just "pull up" the phone's location remotely - that would be a massive security hole. Imagine if a stalker got a hold of that...